# Certain conditions on cancellative semigroups

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

This is extracted from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/192157/cancellable-elements-of-a-power-semigroup) following Benjamin Steinberg's suggestion.

For a semigroup $S,$ let $P(S)$ denote the power semigroup of $S,$ which is made up of all non-empty subsets of $S$ with the operation $AB=\{ab\,|\,a\in A,b\in B\}.$

I'm thining about the following conditions $(P1)$ and $(P2)$ on $S:$

> $(P1)$ Every left-cancellable element of $P(S)$ is a singleton.
>
> $(P2)$ Every cancellable element of $P(S)$ is a singleton.

1) Are the two conditions <strike>equivalent? Are they equivalent for left-cancellative semigroups? Are they</strike> equivalent for cancellative semigroups?

2) Can we characterize semigroups satisfying these conditions? **Left-cancellative ones? Cancellative ones?**

The questions in bold interest me the most. The class of cancellative semigroups satisfying $(P1)$ contains groups and commutative semigroups. From above, any left-cancellative semigroup satisfying $(P1)$ will have to satisfy the right Ore condition.

Comment: I would look at a cancellative semigroup which satisfies the left Ore condition but not the right one. This could potentially gave (P2) but not (P1). Maybe look at baumslag-solitar semigroups.  They have Ore condition on only one side.

Comment: If $S$ is a left-cancellative finite sgrp (either commutative or not), then $SX=SS=S$ for every $X\in P(S)$, with the result that no element of $P(S)$ is left-cancellative, unless $S$ is empty or a singleton, in which case (P1) and (P2) are trivially equivalent. This means that, as far as the focus is on left-cancellative sgrps, you're left (excuse the unintended pun!) with the case where no element of $S$, other than the identity if an identity exists, has finite order.

Comment: I think from previous questions the op is interested in the infinite case

Comment: @Salvo Thank you for your comment, but I think there's some confusion here. $SX=SS$ for all $X$ follows from the _right_ cancellation law on the elements of $S,$ i.e. that the multiplication by $x$ on the right side is injective in $S$. But more importantly, what $SX=SS$ says is not that $X$ is not right-cancellable, but that $S$ is not left-cancellable, which has no bearing on the question I'm asking since that not the same side that the cancellative property that holds in $S$.

Comment: Actually, a right-zero semigroup is left-cancellative and finite, and since its power semigroup is again a right-zero semigroup, it's also left-cancellative.

Comment: Which also shows that my formulation of question 1) was thoughtless since a right zero semigroup satisfies (P2) vacuously and doesn't satisfy (P1). I'll strike the thoughtless part out.

Comment: @Michał. Right, I confused at least a couple of things with others. On a positive note, (P1) and (P2) can be proved to be equivalent if $S$ is a finite group (as far as I can say, you're interested also in the finite case, aren't you?), since then, however we choose $Y,Z\in P(S)$ with $|Y|+|Z| > |S|$, it holds $YZ=S$ (this is a folklore result of additive theory; e.g., it appears as Lemma 3.1.2 in the 3rd chapter of Geroldinger and Ruzsa's _Combinatorial NT and Additive Group Theory_), so that, if $X\in P(S)$ and $|X|\ge 2$, then $XS = XT = SX = TX = S$ for, say, $T:=S\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: @Salvo Yes, I know about this :) I remember contemplating ways to generalize it and not getting very far

Comment: Assume $S$ is a grp (finite or infinite, abelian or not), and suppose to a contradiction that $X$ is left-cancellative for some $X\in P(S)$ with $|X|\ge 2$. Denote by $Y$ the subgrp of $S$ generated by $X$, pick $y\in Y$, and set $Z:=Y\setminus \{y\}$. *Claim*: $X+Y=X+Z$. _Proof_. It's enough to show that $X+y\subseteq X+Z$. For, fix $x_1\in X$ and, using $|X|\ge 2$, let $x_2\in X\setminus \{x_1\}$. Then, note that the equ. $x_1y=x_2z$ is solvable in $Z$, as (i) $x_1,x_2,y\in X$, (ii) $Y$ is a subgrp of $S$, and (iii) $x_2^{-1}x_1y\ne y$. This implies the claim, which gives in turn that [...]

Comment: [...] the left-cancellative elements of P(S) are singletons. And the same reasoning can be now dualized to the case of right-cancellative elements, so we see that, at least on the level of groups, (P1) and (P2) are equivalent. (Hope to have added something to what you already knew!)

Comment: @Salvo I knew that, but it's certainly a good thing to notę. My problem is that I can't really get very far from groups and commutative semigroups. Can you perhaps see a larger class of cancellative semigroups that satisfy (P2), say?